# DNX causing StackOverflowException?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-4.5, stack-overflow, dnx

I have now searched the entire Google (feels like) for this type of related problem, and found nothing...

I have a .Net 4.5.1 website, when building I get a StackOverflowException, with the following Build Output:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException**

There is no stacktrace, or other error information. Although, if I double-click the error message, I get referenced to the Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Target file and the DNX tag (see picture).

I have no problem building or running .Net 4.5.1 websites in other solutions.

[image: Exception]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem. After deleting **project.fragment.lock.json** and **project.lock.json**, the website could build.